# Is a schwa ever stressed?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, ipa, received-pronunciation, weak-forms

Is there a word in RP (Received Pronunciation) where the stressed vowel sound is a schwa?

Comment: I wonder if the *u* in the *un-* prefix qualifies as a schwa. It feels like the same sound in words like *unhappy*.

Comment: @Robusto: Received Pronunciation the *u* in *un-* is ʌ (Open-mid back unrounded) whereas schwa is ə (Mid-central).

Comment: How about "uh". Despite what the dictionaries say (ʌ), I think many Americans pronounce it as a schwa. I don't know about RP, though.

Comment: [The Schwa Was Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Schwa_Was_Here).

Comment: @Peter Shor: in BrE, we spell it *er* (being non-rhotic), and yup, we usually pronounce it as as something fairly close to a schwa.

Comment: Just opinion: Since I was an elementary school student and learned the word "schwa", I have always thought it sounds the same as "u" (what @hippie wrote as ^) (un-,up,ugh!)

Comment: @TecBrat: It could be that the sounds are merged in some dialects. I'll try to think if there are any minimal pairs...

Answer (score 11):

The word *schwa* can mean two things:

> In linguistics, specifically phonetics and phonology, *schwa* (sometimes spelled *shwa*) can mean the following:
>
> - An unstressed and toneless neutral vowel sound in some languages, often but not necessarily a mid-central vowel. Such vowels are often transcribed with the symbol <ə>, regardless of their actual phonetic value.
> - The mid-central vowel sound (rounded or unrounded) in the middle of the vowel chart, stressed or unstressed. In [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) phonetic transcription, it is written as [ə]. In this case the term *mid-central vowel* may be used instead of *schwa* to avoid ambiguity.
>
> — From the [Wikipedia article about schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)

If we go by the first definition, which is a [phonological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology) definition, then the answer is **no**, there are no stressed schwas in Received Pronunciation because *schwa* refers exclusively to unstressed sounds.

If we go by the second definition, which is a purely [phonetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetics) definition, then the answer is a resounding “maybe”. The second definition says “in IPA phonetic transcription” meaning the word *schwa* could refer to a vowel sound (in any language) that has the vowel quality defined as “mid-central”. Traditional phonetic descriptions of [Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) give the vowel quality of the NURSE [lexical set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_sets) as [ɜː], which is the IPA for an [open-mid central unrounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel), a sound very close to but not quite the same as a mid-central vowel. However, a [careful narrow transcription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription) of some particular speaker’s production of the NURSE vowel might be given using the symbol [ə], in which case you could make the claim that this is a “stressed schwa”

Nevertheless, this is a pretty contrived scenario. The usual symbol used to transcribe the NURSE vowel is [ɜː] not [ə].

Comment: The only words I can conceive of that has a stressed schwa (second sense) in English are _but_, _the_, and possibly _just_. Traditionally, the stressed version of _but_ and _just_ have been [ˈbʌt] and [ˈjʌst], but I hear more and more RP speakers stressing them as [ˈbət] and [ˈjəst], with a clearly non-differentiated schwa. _The_ has never, to my knowledge, been stressed as [ˈðʌ] in RP—only [ˈðə] and [ˈðiː] are possible. In other words, when inherently, lexically unstressed monosyllabics receive emphatic stress, they may keep their schwa.

Comment: Since it's necessary to represent stress anyway in English transcription, a stressed schwa is simply a caret (which doesn't occur unstressed in American English, at least). So phonemically, schwa represents all the central vowels, since there is nothing for it to contrast with. One might exclude retroflexed vowels, or represent them as /Vr/ sequence, which would make the vowel of _church_ /ər/.

Answer (score 7):

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa):

> In linguistics, specifically phonetics and phonology, schwa (sometimes spelled shwa) can mean the following:
>
> - An unstressed and toneless neutral vowel sound in some languages, often but not necessarily a mid-central vowel. Such vowels are often transcribed with the symbol <ə>, regardless of their actual phonetic value.
> - The mid-central vowel sound (rounded or unrounded) in the middle of the vowel chart, stressed or unstressed. In IPA phonetic transcription, it is written as [ə]. In this case the term mid-central vowel may be used instead of schwa to avoid ambiguity.

So it seems it has two meanings.  One which by definition is unstressed.  The other which can be in some languages.

Comment: I was wondering whether the IPA vowel /ə/ can be stressed in English words.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike other answers here, the answer is no. The schwa `ə` in **English** IPA transcriptions indicates an unstressed sound.

You can see the [Weak and strong forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_form_and_strong_form) as an example. Same goes for nouns.

Fath**er** is an example, or see this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), where I found this list:

- the 'a' in about [əˈbaʊt]
- the 'e' in taken [ˈteɪkən]
- the 'i' in pencil [ˈpɛnsəl]
- the 'o'
  in eloquent [ˈɛləkwənt]
- the 'u' in supply [səˈplaɪ]
- the 'y' in sibyl [ˈsɪbəl]

---

> **EDIT:**

Like I said under z7sg's answer, I can't understand why some dictionaries disagree.

In the past I had to train for Uni in order to recognize the different "vowel" sounds in English, I'm talking about BrE, and I found this, the [British Council / BBC Phonemic Chart](http://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/try/activities/phonemic-chart).

If you click on `ə`, you will hear a **short schwa sound**, but if you click on `ɜ:` you will clearly hear the same sound but longer, i.e. the **long schwa sound**. I find it quite ambiguous to render those different sounds with the same symbol.

The difference can be heard when saying "[Teach[**er**]](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/teacher)" and "[B[**ir**]d](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/bird)".

See also [this](http://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/think/articles/teaching-schwa). When I used to do IPA transcriptions in my faculty, the schwa always figured in the unstressed syllables.

Comment: @Tim: I added some info, in case you didn't notice.

Comment: @Alenanno: IANA linguist, but as I understand, the difference between the vowels of *teachER* and *EARth* is almost entirely one of length, and vowel length is generally indicated in IPA by `ː`, not by a change of symbol.  There’s no ambiguity in writing `ə` for a short schwa and `əː` for long one, surely?

Comment: @PLL: When I was learning the most common IPA symbols, I knew that unlike other symbols the Schwa is not simply "lengthened" with the usage of :, but you also change the symbol. Even the Phonemic Chart I provided proves me right, and I have other references in case that's not enough. This is what I know by studying, if you know it's the opposite, I'd like to see some references and in that case, I'll understand I'm wrong.

Comment: @PLL: By the way, yes it's a matter of length... I am not sure but I hope I didn't sound too harsh in my comments! :) I just couldn't shut up when I know it's differently, and in the end, we're here to find the true thing, so I'm also ready to be destroyed by someone who brings references for the opposite thing :D eheh

Comment: @Alenanno: What I learned was originally from a rather old IPA handbook aimed at an international audience.  So perhaps my information is out of date; or else perhaps yours is a convention specific to use for English of the IPA? (cont’d)

Comment: According to eg the Wikipedia IPA chart (and others online), `ə` denotes the mid central vowel, `ɜ` the low-mid central.  So perhaps we were both slightly wrong in asserting that length is the only difference between the *teacher* and *earth* vowels?  That would be one explanation (and is the one that Wikipedia supports).  Or else, perhaps, if the difference is just one of length, there could be an English-specific convention to use `ə`/`ɜ` for this distinction rather than `ə`/`əː`, since vowel length isn’t phonemic anywhere else in English?

Comment: No worries about sound harsh, by the way: IRL I am a mathematician, so am similarly quite pedantic about small differences, and quite concerned to get to the bottom of things :-)  Plus, the Wiki-trawling I did for this has introduced me to the magnificent Estonian word *jäääär*!

Comment: @PLL: ahah I see... check the @Peter Shor comment under the other answer. :D what is "jääär" by the way?

Comment: @Alenanno IAANA linguist, but I am confused by the necessity for two symbols for the same sound, if the only difference is that one is longer.  Perhaps the term schwa is problematic, if you are going to make this distinction?  If we restrict schwa to the 'short' unstressed vowel sound then doubtless we could all agree it is not stressed in English.

Comment: @z7sg: Actually, now that you re-mentioned it, if you look at all the vowel sounds, or better, their IPA transcriptions, they are all different from each other. We have a short `ɪ`, but a long `i:`, a short `ɒ`, but a long `ɔ:`, a short `ʊ`, but a long `u:`.

Comment: @Alenanno But the short form of `i:` (ee in see) is not `ɪ` but `i` (y in city).

Comment: @z7sg: This matter is more complex than I initially thought eheh... The only thing I can think of is that we are forgetting or maybe we are not aware of some changes that occur during the Language development...

Comment: @Alenanno, @z7sg: I think @Colin Fine’s comment on the other thread pretty much nails it, actually.  Between the vowels of *earth* and *teacher*, there’s a big difference of length and a slight difference of position.  But since vowel length isn’t generally phonemic in English, the position disctinction (`ə`/`ɜ`) is what gets traditionally used to distinguish them.

Comment: In an old-fashioned Brooklyn accent, *earth* is pronounced with /ɜɪ/ and teacher is pronounced with /ə/. In many modern-day NYC non-rhotic accents, *earth* is pronounced with /ɝ/ and *teacher* is still pronounced with /ə/. Both historically and in many dialects, the difference between *earth* and *teacher* is not just length. I think it makes sense to use a different symbol for them, even if length is the main difference in RP.

Comment: And hey, while we're at it, the examples in that list for E, I, possibly O, and Y are all typically articulated as syllabic consonants, not schwa followed by a consonant. I think it's simply a common (misguided) phonemic concept in English: syllabic consonants just don't exist, so there's obviously got to be a schwa there.

Comment: ɛ <-- is that really a schwa? an EH sound.  Vocal Schwa , in hebrew grammar books anyway, is like you've shown with all your examples with ə

Comment: @Alenanno: I wasn't notified about your edit, but saw it now. I believe your answer is currently the most precise. I'd be enlightened if someone could some up all the wisdom in these comments, though.

Comment: @Peter Shor Why use a different symbol if length is the only difference?  Do you also object to i/i: using the same symbol?

Comment: @barlop: Er... `ɛ` has nothing to do here, I never mentioned it... Don't confuse it with `ɜ`. @Tim When I get a clue, I'll improve the answer :D

Comment: @z7sg: With i/i:, I believe these two vowels are the same historically, and for most English speakers, the length is the only difference. With ə/ə:, I believe the two vowels are historically different, but have converged. I'm not even sure that these two vowels were the same in RP when the IPA was first developed. We need a linguist.

Comment: @Peter Shor The treatment of the i/i:/I phonemes is inconsistent too, at least in wikipedia.  And likewise [constantly changing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_tensing#Happy_tensing)

Comment: @Jon regarding transcribing syllabic consonants as schwa + consonant, I don't think it's a “misguided phonemic concept” per se, rather it is the assertion that syllabic consonants are just the phonetic realization of what is phonologically schwa + those consonants.

Comment: @Peter the IPA symbols are defined independently of their use in transcribing any particular language.

Comment: @nohat: That is essentially what I mean. A phonetic transcription shows what people *actually* say, from an outside perspective, whereas a phonemic transcription shows only what people *think* they're saying, or how they conceptualise it, which is only useful from an in-language standpoint. Dictionaries can use phonemic transcription all they want, but we're talking about phonetics at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

No. Schwa is never stressed in any English word.

The human voice is capable of stressing it of course and schwa is indeed stressed in other languages including Romanian.

Comment: The ə/uh in [səˈplaɪ] supply. that also occurs in some pronunciations of Pencil. pen sul.   Is that not a vocal schwa, occurring in English? I know hebrew has vocal schwa, that is like that.

Comment: @barlop: That syllable isn't stressed, though. Unless you're talking about the adverb of _supple_, in which case it's an `/ʌ/`.

Comment: good point, it's not stressed in supply.. hmm, I was thinking Burn or Dirt  but I see dictionary.cambridge(british pronunciation) /bɜːn/  or /bûrn/ american pronunciation.  no upside down e at all so I suppose it's not even a schwa?

Comment: @barlop: Hebrew schwa/sheva is quite different than English schwa. It has both silent and pronounced versions. But I don't know much more as my Hebrew never advanced very far (-:

Comment: @hippietrail the silent one hebrew has does nothing probably isn't even a sound, it might just be a mark to symbolise no sound to help prevent a scribe from accidentally putting one in.  But the vocal schwa in hebrew has a few pronunications some use one, some use another, a common one is ə  the same as schwa in English.  It could be that in hebrew it doesn't have stress either or rarely does.

Comment: @barlop: Off Topic but... the Hebrew sheva is not just the mark but a key concept in Hebrew grammar that ties deeply with syllabics and word-formation and seemed to come up everywhere when I was into Hebrew grammar. If we had a Hebrew Language & Usage site it would be a bottomless source of questions. The Wikipedia gets complicated really quickly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shva

Comment: @hippietrail Nothing is just a mark. I'm not denying the grammatical aspect, there are grammatical rules to determine whether it's vocal or silent.  The silent one doesn't do anything.  A teacher in conversation asked the question of what its purpose is, and suggested that maybe it's to help prevent the scribe accidentally putting a different mark in there. (e.g. one wouldn't want a little dot finding its way there 'cos that would be a vowel).

Comment: @hippietrail  I don't think it's like other or most other vowel marks where people had to memorize them. If you rubbed them all out, the simple one (i'm not sure about rubbing the : part of compound ones out!), but if you rubbed simple ones out then you'd be in the same position. 'cos the simple ones just sit under consonants with no other vowel(apart from, if I recall, gutteral consonants that don't take one). The symbol itself tells us nothing about how to pronounce it. It's obvious when it should be there. And Grammatical rules tell us how to pronounce it i.e. whether vocal or silent.

Comment: in hebrew the silent shwa is at the end of a syllable and the vocal one is at the start of a syllable. The silent one is like the de"B"ra.  or de"N"tal.  The vocal one is like "B"anana

Comment: Unreferenced answers may come across as pure opinion. And when they are contradicted by references in other answers....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **stressed schwa** seems to occur in some British dialects.

**Stressed schwa** occurs in other languages. Here's an excellent excerpt from [Wells 2014](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/phonetics-and-phonology/sounds-interesting-observations-english-and-general-phonetics?format=HB&isbn=9781107074705):

[image]

[Oostendorp 2000](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110809244/9783110809244.229/9783110809244.229.xml) astutely observes that **schwa "avoids stressed positions"** [emphasis mine - Alex B.].

Comment: I would take issue with this (rather than say out-and-out "It's wrong). My southern-England English certainly doesn't pronounce *'cause* the same as a stressed *(be)cause;* the adverb *just* the same when it's stressed as unstressed; or the two syllables of *gonna* the same. There is a qualitative difference.

Comment: @Andrew: I actually always pronounce *just* (the adverb) with a schwa, even when it's stressed, so it differs from *just* (the adjective). But I believe that's an idiosyncrasy, and not typical in American speech. Wells's quote is probably just saying that some British speakers do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

What about word because? Especially it's weak form. According to Collin's, Cambridge, Oxford dictionary it's /bɪˈkəz/.

Comment: You cannot — by definition — have a stressed schwa. The OED has /bɪˈkɔːz/ or /bɪˈkɒz/ there, and those with the *cot–caught* merge get /bɪˈkʌz/ with /bəˈkʌz/ in fast speech due to reduction. Yes, those can all reduce to schwa when unstressed, but when stressed, they get different identities. And the second syllable, being stressed, howsoever you should fold, spindle, or mutilate it, you cannot get to a schwa. Only when in very fast speech where the entire word loses stress (and most of its first syllable) can /b(ə)kəz/ occur. So it can occur in fast, connected speech but not otherwise.

Comment: I’ve looked into this a bit more carefully, and I discover that with Oxford Dictionaries Online, [their IPA for UK English is /bɪˈkɒz/](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/because), which agrees with the OED (well, in part) and is to be expected. The [/bēˈkəz/ you find there under the American English entry for that word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/because) is ***not* written in actual IPA**, as its first vowel reveals. It uses some misleading faux-pronunciation respelling system, and therefore its schwa isn’t a real one.

Comment: The weak form of *because* has ***no*** stressed syllables: it should be written in IPA as /bɪkəz/. In sentences where the syllable following *because* is stressed, /bɪkəz/ is perfectly normal in speech. But it's not a schwa in a stressed syllable. Similarly, the weak forms of *just* and *but* have schwas, but they're not stressed syllables (despite the fact that they are single-syllable words).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. When it comes to words like 'just', 'but', 'that' and so one, I understand it. But I was astonished with 'because', especially that in Collins and Cambridge dictionaries the stress is marked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first vowel in "children" is pretty damn close to a stressed schwa. Dictionaries tend to list it as a short i, to which I say, maybe in your dialect. But I think it's probably unique.

Comment: Is your dialect RP, as asked about in the question?

Comment: Yep. Faintly US-influenced, as I grew up there, but I spent most of my life in the south of England prior to 2004, and that's what I'm used to hearing.

Answer (score -3):

Of course it can appear in the stressed syllable. It always occurs in the mono-syllabic articles 'the'and 'a' (except in certain syntactic exceptions like 'the elephant').

Comment: But these are not stressed.

Comment: But what do you mean by 'these'?  The articles may not take the nuclear stress in a longer utterance, but as the syllabic vowel they are stressed.  Stress is represented by a syllable, and a syllable must, by definition, contain a vowel. So the schwa is indeed 'stressed'