# American vs British pronunciation in a word: "run", how should that be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, transatlantic-differences

As far as I know, words like *run* or *under* (letter: "u") are pronounced as:

1. British: /rʌn/
2. American: /rən/ with the schwa sound

The above is according to the page: [A Key To English Pronunciations — Lexico/Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/key-to-pronunciation)

Now I wanted to confirm that in the dictionaries.

1. Merriam Webster dictionary shows: \ˈrən\
2. All other show: /rʌn/

The difference between: ʌ and ə is really subtle ... if any ...
In my opinion the recording on Merriam Webster dictionary says more like: ʌ than ə

In: ə the mouth is slightly opened and relaxed
In: ʌ is more open than for: "ə"

How should that really be pronounced? Where can I find the recording so that I could hear the difference?

Comment: _Run_ is one of those words which are pronounced differently in different parts of the UK!

Comment: Some Americans have the same vowel (although stressed and unstressed) in *run* and *about*. Others don't. How do dictionaries decide which Americans' pronunciations to record? I don't know.

Comment: @KateBunting have you got any examples of the difference (or regions)? I can only think of examples where the 'R' differs in sound - the 'u' is pretty much the same sound afaik (just out of curiosity).

Comment: @Smock It's pretty well-known that southern English speakers typically pronounce 'u' as 'uh' (in extreme RP, more like 'ah'), while northerners pronounce it as 'oo' (so _bus_ and _put_ have the same vowel).

Comment: @KateBunting Ahh yes, I can see that now. I can imagine 'bus' a bit like as 'boose' in a Liverpool accent now) - Thanks.

Comment: In American English, [ʌ] is the stressed allophone of /ə/. I.e, there's no phonemic difference between them, as long as you allow stress as a conditioning environment (which it plainly is, for the other vowels). In the UK, it's a different story, with FAR more variation.

Comment: I've found forvo.com a good resource for recordings, though that might be a bit too formal of a context for real linguistic research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between /ʌ/ and /ə/ in English IPA](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404348/difference-between-%ca%8c-and-%c9%99-in-english-ipa)

Answer (score -2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In American English, [ʌ] is the stressed allophone of /ə/. I.e, there's no phonemic difference between them, as long as you allow stress as a conditioning environment (which it plainly is, for the other vowels). In the UK, it's a different story, with FAR more variation.