# I dont understand ‘Stressed schwa’

Tags: phonology, phonetics

how can a ‘stressed schwa’ exist?
In ‘Applied English Phonology 3rd edition’ (page 85), ‘herder’ is the example of the stressed schwa and it is manifested as ‘3’(with r-coloring tail).
As I’ve seen so far, a schwa is so light that the syllable containing it cannot be stressed despite the following coda.
Thank you

Comment: which syllable does it list as stressed schwa, the first or the second? And American or British Pronunciation?

Comment: ‘herder’ has stress on the first syllable. And we may infer that it is American judging from ‘r-coloring’

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/is-a-schwa-ever-stressed might be helpful, but focuses on britsh accent's potential use of stressed schwa. I would also add that "murder", "third", "turd", "burn", "urn" etc. to your list